# Regex- Get file name after last '\'

Tags: regex

I have file name like 
    **C:\fakepath\CI_Logo.jpg**.
I need a regex for getting CI_Logo.jpg. Tried with `\\[^\\]+$`, but didn't workout..

Below is my Javascript Code

```
var regex="\\[^\\]+$"; 
var fileGet=$('input.clsFile').val();
var fileName=fileGet.match(regex);
alert(fileName);
```

Comment: What language are you using? Your regex seems to be fine. How are you using it? You can simply use `[^\\]+$`.

Comment: @RohitJain Maybe he doesn't want the backslash in his results ? This should work `[^\\]+$` ...

Comment: Asking for "a regex" makes no sense. There's BREs and EREs and PREs and others, all used by different tools. Instead of asking for "a regex", ask for a solution in whatever tool(s) you want to use. An RE may not even be appropriate at all, maybe a string or character search and replacement makes more sense.

Comment: I am implementing this in javascript. But still am not getting the solution. I am getting it as null @RohitJain

Comment: Have you considered that certain people write their path names with /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimalist approach: [**demo**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5B%5Cw%5Cd_%5C.%5D%2b%5C.%5B%5Cw%5Cd%5D%2b%29%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D&input=C%3a%5Cfakepath%5CCI_Logo.jpg)

```
([\w\d_\.]+\.[\w\d]+)[^\\]
```

Comment: This also matches `CI_Logo.jpg` in `C:\fakepath\CI_Logo.jpg\something` where it should actually match `something`. Remember that folders may also contain dots and that file names do not necessarily contain an extension!

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
String oldFileName = "slashed file name";
String[] fileNameWithPath = oldFileName.split("\\\\");
int pathLength = fileNameWithPath.length;
oldFileName = fileNameWithPath[pathLength-1];
```

in java,
I guess,You can modify this for any other langs.

Edit:
make sure you split with **"\\\\"** - four slashes

Comment: Yeah, a split should be the best solution for this problem... but this code can be improved. Since we know that the filename is always in the last position of the array we just have to acees it :)

Comment: Yes this can be optimized, but here providing the elaborated answer.

Comment: Alternatively, in .NET: `Path.GetFilename(...)`